# How can I add line breaks into a tibble output in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I am writing an R script that is pulling expected outputs of various data sets and then putting those into a tibble that will be later exported into Excel.

I want to keep a row for each data set and then the last column will have five example outputs.

I can create a string like `2021 :: 2039909\n2020 :: 1096166\n2019 :: 195718\n2018 :: 6209\n2017 :: 1547` that has the example outputs.

But when I try to put those into a tibble I can't figure out how to convert the `\n` into a line break. When I try `cat` or `writeLines` I get

```
Error in vec_rbind(old, new) : 
  Internal error in `vec_assign()`: `value` should have been recycled to fit `x`.
```

I get it when I try
`data <- add_row(data, values = writeLines(dataset))`

where dataset would be
`2021 :: 2039909\n2020 :: 1096166\n2019 :: 195718\n2018 :: 6209\n2017 :: 1547`

I definitely will appreciate any help you can give me!

Comment: Why do you want to convert `2021 :: 2039909\n2020 :: 1096166\n2019 :: 195718\n2018 :: 6209\n2017 :: 1547` into line breaks? Do you want them as separate rows in tibble?

Comment: It's a weird issue, totally. Basically, I'm combining information from three different sources to save time having to look up examples and background. The ```2021 :: 2039909\n2020 :: 1096166\n2019 :: 195718\n2018 :: 6209\n2017 :: 1547``` is three examples of the usage of a particular variable with each line being a different example. In the end, I'd have line-items that describe my data and the last column would have three examples